# Character issue in iphone app

Tags: iphone, character-encoding

I'm downloading a file from the server to my iPhone app. but inside the text file I cannot read these characters

> áéíóú

Is there any method to read the characters?

Comment: what does "but inside tht text file i cannot read these characters"? Show some of your code.

Comment: NSString *stringFromFileAtPath = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:docFilePath];

Answer (score 0):

Try with `+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error` . You have to find out, what encoding is used for the file and use it. Here's a [list of available encodings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) (Jump To ... NSStringEncoding).

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. but which encoding method should i use to read the content. also im saving content to the sqlite db